# Date in input is different from the one saved in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, strongloop, apic

I am using a type date to get the date but the date that i picked and the date that is saved inside the database is different. The date that is saved will always be the one day before the date that i picked. For example, in my input the date is 8 august but in the database it's saved as 7 august. How do i go abt fixing this and also how do i display the date without the T16:00:00.000Z. [image: displayed date]

## dairy.html

```
<div>
<label> Date: </label>  
<input type="date" ng-model="diary.date">
</div>
```

## data.html

```
<table style="width:90%"  align="center" class="t3" ng-controller="RetrieveDiaryController">
      <tr>
        <th style="width:40%">Date</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Type</th>
        <th style="width:30%">Level</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in diaries | orderBy:'date':true">
        <td>{{d.date}}</td>
        <td>{{d.taken}}</td>
        <td>{{d.level}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

## health.js

.

```
controller('TrackingController', ['$scope', 'Diary', '$state', function($scope, Diary, $state) {
    $scope.diaries = [];

$scope.submitForm = function() {
  Diary
    .upsert({
      date: $scope.diary.date,
      taken: $scope.diary.taken,
      level: $scope.diary.level
    })
    .$promise
    .then(function() {
      $state.go('data');
    });
};
  }])
    .controller('RetrieveDiaryController', ['$scope', 'Diary', function ($scope, Diary) {
       $scope.diaries = Diary.find();
    }])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the timezone values of the date and some difference in it between the machine you input the date and the server the db runs on. If you want to just save the simple date string, use Date object methods like getDay() or getFullYear to create a date string and then save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS` is the standart ISO datetime format for `UTC`. If you want to get it in `YYYY-MM-DD` format without converting it to local time, you can do it like this.

```
//used for padding left with 0 on one character strings. e.g. "1" => "01"
var pad = function(str){ str = str.toString(); return "00".substring(0, 2-str.length) + str; }

var date = new Date("2016-08-02T16:00:00.000Z");
var utcdatestring = date.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + pad(date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + pad(date.getUTCDate());
console.log(utcdatestring); //Logs "2016-08-02"
```

However, I highly recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), since working with dates in javascript is really cumbersome with vanilla javascript.

```js
var date = moment.utc("2016-08-02T23:00:00.000Z"); //parse datetime string as utc date
var utcdatestring = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"); //use .format() to get date string in any format you want
console.log(utcdatestring); // Logs "2016-08-02"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the basic date Filter or angular**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl" ng-model="test='2016-08-02T16:00:00.000Z'">
   <p>Date = {{ test| date }}</p>
  </div>
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
});
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```